# Why does the same code called first by bash and then by emacs not behave the same way?

Tags: bash, script

I have this LaTeX code:

```
%% test.tex
\begin{wrapfig}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{fig1.eps}\end{wrapfig}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{fig2.eps}
```

I have a script called `fix-files-ext.sh` that fixes the extensions of graphic files (in this example it will change `.eps` to `.pdf`).

My script is this:

```
## fix-files-ext.sh
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
emacs "$1" --batch -l ~/fix-files-ext.el ## &> /dev/null
```

where `fix-files-ext.el` contains this code:

```
;; fix-files-ext.el
(save-excursion
  (let* ((case-fold-search nil))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "\\\\includegraphics" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (let* ((pos1 (copy-marker (progn
                                    (when (looking-at "\\(?:[ \n]+\\)?\\[")
                                      (forward-sexp))
                                    (point))))
               (pos2 (copy-marker (progn
                                    (forward-sexp)
                                    (point)))))

          (if (re-search-backward "\\.\\(e?ps\\|E?PS\\)}" pos1 t)
              (replace-match ".pdf}" t)
            (if (re-search-backward "\\.\\(JBIG2\\|JPEG\\|JP2\\|JPG\\|JPX\\|PDF\\|PNG\\)}" pos1 t)
                (replace-match (downcase (match-string 0)) t)
              (if (re-search-backward "\\.\\(tiff?\\|TIFF?\\)}" pos1 t)
                  (replace-match ".png}" t)))))))

    (save-buffer)))
```

Here is the output I get calling my script:

```
$ bash fix-files-ext.sh test.tex
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/00debian.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely", 54, 67
```

The `Scan error` refers to the second `forward-sexp`. But if I open `test.tex` with emacs and load `fix-files-ext.el` with `load-file`, it works perfectly. Why does this happen?

**Remarks**

In reference to `$ bash fix-files-ext.sh test.tex`:

1. If I drop `\end{wrapfig}`, it works.
2. If I leave `\end{wrapfig}` and change the second `forward-sexp` to `forward-list`, it works.

For me it is preferable to use `forward-sexp` instead of `forward-list` because if there were unbalanced brackets in the file names of the figures, `forward-list` would fail unlike `forward-sexp` (I am a professional typesetter and sometimes it happens that the names of the figures are a bit exotic).

Beyond that, I would like to understand why the same code called first by bash and then by emacs doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Try the following: start with `emacs -Q`, open `test.tex` and then `M-x load-file RET fix-file-ext.el` - I still get the Scan error in this case. If you are doing it in your working emacs and it succeeds, it's probably the case that your environment is different (e.g. maybe you are using AucTeX in your working emacs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a difference between your working emacs (where you presumably load `auctex` - or some other package which somehow works around or hides the problem; see comments for some discussion) and a bare emacs, started with `-q` or `--batch` (Note that `--batch` implies `-q`).

If I open the file in my working emacs (where `auctex` is active), and do `M-x load-file RET fix-file-ext.el`, the file is changed and saved.

If I run `emacs --batch test.tex -l ./fix-file-ext.el`, then I get a `Scan` error.

If I run `emacs -q` and open `test.tex` and then run `M-x load-file RET fix-file-ext.el` I *still* get a scan error.

Finally, if I do a batch run but load my init file:

```
emacs --batch -l ~/.config/emacs/init.el test.tex -l ./fix-file-ext.el
```

it succeeds.

I also tried loading *just* `auctex` instead of my whole init file:

```
emacs --batch -l /path/to/auctex-config.el test.tex -l ./fix-file-ext.el
```

and that worked as well.

So for some reason (which I have not investigated), `auctex` changes the behavior of `forward-sexp` (or rather the function `latex-forward-sexp` which is the one used in LaTeX buffers - see the variable `forward-sexp-function`). That's probably a bug in the built-in `tex-mode.el`.

Comment: @ NickD It can't be AucTeX's fault because I don't have it installed. Anyway I tried adding my init file and now it works perfectly!

Comment: You might want to find out exactly *which* part of your init file does the trick by bisecting it. In my case, I was able to get it to work with just auctex, but since I don't really know *why* it works with `auctex`, but not without it, I'd have to bisect further to pinpoint exactly what causes the behavior (or I could look at the sources and try to edebug it, since I know how to reproduce it interactively). It would be good to verify if it is indeed a bug and report it.

Comment: And BTW, I'm not saying it is `auctex`'s fault at all. I believe it's a bug in the `latex-forward-sexp` function in `tex-mode.el` and `auctex` actually does something to *fix* it (or at least to hide it).

Comment: Ok, I belive I've found what does the trick: my init file loads the functions defined [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2004-09/msg00350.html). With these functions loaed, all it works. Without them, I get "scan error".